# How to automatically create documentation for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Is there anything like Javadoc in JavaScript? In Java I just clicked generate JavaDoc and it created a website with my documented code. What is the equivalent in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of them:

- [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app)
- [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org)
- [documentJS](https://documentjs.com)
- [documentation.js](https://documentation.js.org)
- [YUIDoc](https://yui.github.io/yuidoc/)
- [TypeDoc](https://typedoc.org) // For TypeScript
- [NgDOCX](https://ngdocx.herokuapp.com/home) // For Angular
- [Docco](http://ashkenas.com/docco/)

Comment: Do you know some tools which can generate documentation when there is no tag / markers / comments inside ?
(I am sorry to ask this question whereas this question is closed. I am lost and I have no idea how to have the answer in another way. Very very sorry !!!)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html).

Quoting the documentation of JSDoc:

> JSDoc 3 is an API documentation generator for JavaScript, similar to Javadoc or phpDocumentor. You add documentation comments directly to your source code, right alongside the code itself. The JSDoc tool will scan your source code and generate an HTML documentation website for you.